# Ways to free up extra space?

Tags: 14.04, disk-usage, cache

I'm running dangerously low on disk space (about 300mb left of my 16gb capacity) and I need to find out how I could get rid of things I don't need.

Comment: Start the `Disk Usage Analyzer` and see if you can tell where your space has gone. Old kernels in /boot, files in /tmp, /var are all candidates where stuff gets lost.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are talking about your root (/) partition.
 If there are not large packages(programms) to uninstall, open **Synaptic** or install it in terminal if you don't have it,

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

then write *linux* in the shearch field, press once the "S" symbol in the first column so the installed packages come first in the list, find the 4-packages groups for the kernel versions and mark for removal all **accept** the two (4-packages groups) with the newest versions.
 **Be very careful, this can destroy your system if you do it wrong!** My image doesn't help much, because it is from a just-new install, if it had several kernel-updates you would see multiple 4-package groups with different version-numbers. If you also have only one or two 4-package groups, **do not follow my instructions**.

[image: Don't play with these toys]

You could also try to extend "/" partition (if it is not on a 16GB SSD), or install a lighter Linux OS.